# Formating int datetime in codeigniter mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, codeigniter, datetime

I have Datetime in integer in database.

Example. 1597192194

How can convert that in to date format dd-mm-yy h:i:s.

I have tried this one, not it's not working.

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') as registered_on");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(created_on), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as registered_on
```

Rationale:

- `from_unixtime()` converts your epoch timestamp to a `datetime` value
- then `date_format()` applies the target format

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d73a63e47382f54ea604990779e90f11)**:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(1597192194), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as registered_on
```

```
| registered_on       |
| :------------------ |
| 12-08-2020 01:29:54 |
```